# XPath condition returning "wrong" node

Tags: xpath

When doing something like `/entries/entry/key='test'`, I always get the node key returned.
But I want the entry node. How can I get it?

My XML looks like this:

```
<entries>
     <entry>
           <key>test</key>
     </entry>
</entries>
```

Comment: Do note tha `/entries/entry/key='test'` it's an existencial comparison. I should return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to select the entry node and match subelement "key"'s value to the text 'test' .  This should do it:

```
/entries/entry[key='test']
```